# Plotting a graph by month wise in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scikit-learn, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset: `df.head(4)`

```
               Dewptm   Fog  Humidity   Pressurem     Tempm      Wspdm  Rainfall
datetime_utc                            
1996-11-01    11.666667 0.0  52.916667  -2659.666667  22.333333  2.466667   0
1996-11-02    10.458333 0.0  48.625000  1009.833333   22.916667  8.028571   0
1996-11-03    12.041667 0.0  55.958333  1010.500000   21.791667  4.804545   0
1996-11-04    10.222222 0.0  48.055556  1011.333333   22.722222  1.964706   0
```

How could I plot the histogram of Rainfall for each month.
I dont know the exact approach however, I have tried something like this, but not succeed.

```
df.groupby([df['datetime_utc'].dt.month_name()], sort=False).sum().plot(kind="bar",figsize=(18,5),stacked=True,align='center',width=0.9)
plt.ylabel('Rainfall (mm)')
plt.xlabel('Year Wise')
```

But I am getting error: `KeyError: 'datetime_utc'`

Please suggest me how ccould I plot the graph for each month for a column Rainfall.

Comment: I think you need to reset the index before calling your groupby function

Comment: Consider using the `.resample()` method, which will do the same thing without resetting the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DamianoC. says, `datetime_utc` is your index. So either do:

```
df = df.reset_index()

df.groupby([df['datetime_utc'].dt.month_name()], sort=False).sum().plot(kind="bar",figsize=(18,5),stacked=True,align='center',width=0.9)
plt.ylabel('Rainfall (mm)')
plt.xlabel('Year Wise')
```

Or

```
df.groupby([df.index.month_name()], sort=False).sum().plot(kind="bar",figsize=(18,5),stacked=True,align='center',width=0.9)
plt.ylabel('Rainfall (mm)')
plt.xlabel('Year Wise')
```

However, it's recommend not to use string as index for plot. Instead, do `df.index.month` and modify the label with `ax.set_xticklabels()`. For example, if your data starts with `2018-06-04`, you would get some graph like this, noting how the `x-axis` starts with June.

[image]

While, you can use `df.index.month` and get:

[image]